# Footable 10th page need to Show when it loads

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, footable

I am working on a Web project.I used Footable to show Data.Now am showing 100 more data on footable ,Pagination is already so page numbers are like this << < 1 2 3 4 5 ... > >> .  when data loads the 1 st page is active now i need to set as 10 th page when it loads.I tried this code

```
$('.footable-page a').filter('[data-page="10"]').trigger('click');
```

but it is not working Anyone please give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

Change footable pagination library javascript file 
with

```
function Paginate(pageno){
     newpage=pageno;
}
```